# How to GCC compile without _alloca?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, alloca

For some reason, I should use gcc to compile a C file, then link against Visual C++ 2008 project.

(I used the current latest gcc version: cygwin gcc 4.3.4 20090804.)

But there is one problem: gcc always allocate a big array with _alloca,

and VC linker can't resolve the symbol __alloca.

for example,

```
int func()
{
    int big[10240];
    ....
}
```

this code makes the _alloca dependency although I didn't call the _alloca function explicitly.

(array size matters. if i change 10240 -> 128, everything ok)

I tried gcc option -fno-builtin-alloca or -fno-builtin, but no luck.

Is it possible to make gcc not to use _alloca ? (or adjust the threshold?)

Comment: Why not just use `malloc()` explicitly?

Comment: It's not my written source and somewhat complex to edit. and maybe the original author did not want the penalty to call malloc.

Comment: The purpose of alloca in this case is to make sure the stack is large enough to hold this array. The Microsoft compiler doesn't need alloca; it emits this stack probe code directly into the function. The stack probe isn't needed when the locals are small. What happens if you don't use -fno-builtin-alloca and -fno-builtin?

Comment: Oh dear, 10k is a **huge** object to put on the stack, and is a horrible idea regardless of whether it works or not.  Can you change the code not to do this?

Comment: @ephe: (1) It's not his code. (2) Changing to `malloc` without appropriate `free` causes leak.

Comment: Actually, it's more than 10k: if an `int` is 4B, then this array is 40kB.  While it may not cause immediate problems on your current platform, it's still inadvisable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118011

Comment: @Tim: specifying -fno-builtin* or not did not affect anything. I read _alloca is built-in, but I wonder why -fno-builtin doesn't disable it.

Comment: @ephe: 10240 is an example. "char big[4096]" also generates _alloca call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best thing to do would be to compile all code with VC++. If that's not possible..

You should use the [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) gcc instead of the cygwin one. It's designed to output code that will be linked against the VC++ runtime, not the cygwin libraries. In particular, it will call the VC++ runtime function __chkstk instead of __alloca.

Comment: I tried MinGW (gcc 3.4.5 mingw-vista special r3) and compiled a simple C source. but the dumpbin result showed __alloca dependency:

dumpbin /symbols test.obj
...
00C 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __alloca
...
is there a special option for mingw?

Comment: Ah, sorry. The mingw.org gcc does this. The TDM GCC 4.x mingw build outputs __chkstk. http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/

Comment: Thank you. I checked TDM gcc always outputs __chkstk, but VC2008 outputs _chkstk on Release build, and _alloca_probe on Debug build. I think I should edit the code to use local varaibles under 4K.

Answer (score 3):

You could just write your own _alloca routine and link against that. Look at the gcc library source to see what it's supposed to do.

Comment: When I implemented _alloca in VS2008, I got: error C2169: '_alloca' : intrinsic function, cannot be defined

Comment: I think you'd probably want to implement your custom _alloca using gcc rather then Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [_alloca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5%28VS.80%29.aspx) has been deprecated by Microsoft and is no longer in their runtime libraries after VS2005.  Newer runtime libraries support [_malloca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Your options don't look good.  You can try to build with VS2005 instead.  Perhaps cygwin has an option where you can tell it you are using a newer runtime library (and if they don't support that yet, you could file it as a feature request).

Answer (score 0):

some related discussions:

- [cygwin: gcc and alloca](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-03/msg01228.html)
- [GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gccint_166.html)
- [gcc and alloca](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/218021-gcc-alloca)